# c size_t variable not being set to zero?

Tags: c, struct, size-t

I am trying to set the total_elements to 0 but it ends up giving me a random large number. I am severely confused as to why this is occurring. Here are my structs:

```
typedef struct sack {
  Element *elements;
  size_t total_elements;
} Sack;

typedef struct element {
  char *name;
  int occurances;
  struct element *next;
} Element;
```

and here's the code:

```
void init_sack(Sack *sack) {
  if(!(sack = calloc(1, sizeof(Sack)))) {
    return;
  }
  sack->elements = NULL;
  sack->total_elements = 0;
  return;
}
```

Comment: It is set to 0. Why do you think it isn't? How would you know?

Comment: @immibis gdb the value it is something like 131567. And code where I check if total_elements = 0 is not working

Comment: @BLUEPIXY some explanation please?

Comment: The argument to the function itself can not be changed within the function.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what should I do, then?

Comment: option 1) `void init_sack(Sack *sack) {` --> `void init_sack(Sack **sack) {`.. `*sack = calloc(1, sizeof(Sack))`, Call like `init_sack(&sack_pointer);` option 2) `Sack  *init_sack(Sack *sack) {`... `return sack;`. Call like `sack_pointer = init_sack(sack_pointer);`

Comment: Only the local copy of sack you passed to init_sack is being modified. Whatever you passed from the callee will still remain pointing to its original value, in your case junk. So you. Need to either return sack and assign it to the variable or pass a pointer to the pointer and set it appropriately here.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya i cannot change the function's return type or parameters. What other option is there?

Comment: Your other option then would be to call calloc/malloc in the caller itself and pass sack so the members can be initialised to 0 and NULL.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya what do you mean in the caller?

Comment: The other function from where you are calling init_sack. main maybe?

Comment: `void init_sack(Sack *sack) {
  if(!sack){
    sack->elements = NULL;
    sack->total_elements = 0;
  }
}`...`Sack sack; init_sack(&sack);` or `Sack *sack = malloc(sizeof *sack); init_sack(sack);`

Comment: @user7252850 Tip for the future: post the code that calls the functions too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from `init_sack`'s type and name, it looks like it is supposed to merely initialize an existing `Sack`, not allocate a new one.

In that case the solution would be:

```
void init_sack(Sack *sack) {
  sack->elements = NULL;
  sack->total_elements = 0;
}
```

Call as either:

```
Sack sack;
init_sack(&sack);
```

or:

```
Sack *sack = malloc(sizeof *sack);
if (!sack) handle_error_somehow(...);
init_sack(sack);
```

Comment: I concur. `init_sack` must have been declared for initialising and not for allocating.

Comment: Upvoted for not forgetting `if (!sack) handle_error_somehow(...);`

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating memory to Sack *sack which is local to init_sack, this local variable is lost once function is returned

You need to either return sack from init_sack or pass it as double pointer to init_sack so that allocated pointers value can be accessible in caller function of init_sack

Comment: if I cannot do either of those what option do I have?